# iOS - different response from single API in ARC and parsing

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing

In my project i am passing this API: http://dev-demo.info.bh-in-15.webhostbox.net/dv/nationalblack/api/businessbysubcat with params: `prod_id=25,var_id=140`.
The problem is when i am pass this api in Rest Client it displays correct response but when i am trying to put it in my code it shows different response.

i am using the following code:

```
-(void)listofNotice
{
    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"prod_id=25,var_id=140"];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dev-demo.info.bh-in-15.webhostbox.net/dv/nationalblack/api/businessbysubcat"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *err;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

    //NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //NSLog(@"str : %@",str);

    NSDictionary *dict6 = [self cleanJsonToObject:responseData];
    NSLog(@"str : %@",dict6);

}


- (id)cleanJsonToObject:(id)data
{
    NSError* error;
    if (data == (id)[NSNull null])
    {
        return [[NSObject alloc] init];
    }
    id jsonObject;
    if ([data isKindOfClass:[NSData class]])
    {
        jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    }
    else
    {
        jsonObject = data;
    }
    if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    {
        NSMutableArray *array = [jsonObject mutableCopy];
        for (int i = (int)array.count-1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            id a = array[i];
            if (a == (id)[NSNull null])
            {
                [array removeObjectAtIndex:i];
            } else
            {
                array[i] = [self cleanJsonToObject:a];
            }
        }
        return array;
    }
    else if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [jsonObject mutableCopy];
        for(NSString *key in [dictionary allKeys])
        {
            id d = dictionary[key];
            if (d == (id)[NSNull null])
            {
                dictionary[key] = @"";
            } else
            {
                dictionary[key] = [self cleanJsonToObject:d];
            }
        }
        return dictionary;
    }
    else
    {
        return jsonObject;
    }
}
```

it display the following response:

```
str : {
    business = 0;
    "business-list" = "Business list empty.";
    response = 401;
}
```

but the actual response is something like this

[image]

please help me.. Thanks In advance

Comment: Are you doing some authentication before calling the API because it is giving 401 in response. Though it is not the correct way to do it

Comment: @abhi : It should be problem in back-end deseralization. Use AFNetwokring and in that use AFJSONRequestSerializer to pass the data as paramter. When you are sending in normal way in backend they might get null values. AFJSONRequestSerializer helps you send parameters in proper json format.

Comment: it works now the only mistake i did in my code was i am using , instead of &

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change this

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"prod_id=25,var_id=140"];
```

To:

```
NSString * post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"prod_id=25&var_id=140"];
```

if possible use this:

```
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
        configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = @{@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" :  @"Content-Type"};
        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dev-demo.info.bh-in-15.webhostbox.net/dv/nationalblack/api/businessbysubcat"];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

      NSData *requestData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
      [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
      [request setHTTPBody:requestData];

      NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)                                                                              {   
  if (data != nil){
    NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
    NSInteger code = [httpResponse statusCode];
    NSLog(@"Status Code: %ld", (long)code);

  if (code == 200) {
    NSError *error;
    id responseObject =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
   }
  }                                                                              
}];

[postDataTask resume];
```

OR

```
    NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"prod_id=%@&var_id=%@",@"25",@"140"];
    NSURL *urlPath = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dev-demo.info.bh-in-15.webhostbox.net/dv/nationalblack/api/businessbysubcat"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:urlPath
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30.0];

    NSData *requestData = [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:requestData];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        [APP_DELEGATE removeLoader];

        if(data != nil) {
            NSDictionary *responseObject =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
            NSLog(@" %@", responseObject);
        }
        else {
        }
    }];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change below code

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"prod_id=25,var_id=140"];
```

to

```
NSDictionary *prodDict=@{@"prod_id":@"25",
                         @"var_id":@"140"};
```